# Misalignment and Black/Blank upload when cropping images with Croppie.js and a Modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image, croppie

When working on a website on my local server, I came across an issue with [Croppie.js](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/). The issue only happens when a modal is used to crop the image — for example, everything works fine here:
`[codepen]`(https://codepen.io/azerafati/pen/VzOGRe)

I was able to reconstruct the issue on Codepen using the following image.

[image: Image to upload]

### The Issue

With a modal on Codepen, the issue only happens in the Editor view — Image B:
`[codepen]`(https://codepen.io/amatek/pen/GREvEbG). Surprisingly, everything seems to work as expected in the Details view — Image A: `[codepen]`(https://codepen.io/amatek/details/GREvEbG).

[image: Codepen: (A) Details view; (B) Editor view]

**Normal behaviour:** When using the zoom slider on the modal in the Details view, the image is transformed from the center.

[image]

**The bug:** However, the image is transformed from a corner when in the Editor view. This somehow leads to a black image being uploaded when the *crop* button is clicked.

[image]

Sometimes (depending on the amount of zoom applied), instead of a black image:

- only the left side of the image is uploaded with the right side is
  cut off; or
- the image is uploaded zoomed in to the corner.

There is still misalignment even when the zoom is not applied.

### Environment

From my tests so far, this issue does not happen on mobile browsers (although I only tested with Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox). I have noticed the issue on Desktops with Windows 7 and 10 (I am yet to test on other Operating Systems).

Bug Present

- **Windows 10:** Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge
- **Windows 7:** Microsoft Edge

No Bug

- **Windows 10:** Mozilla Firefox
- **Windows 7:** Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox

### My Efforts so far

I have tried debugging the [croppie.css](https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie/blob/master/croppie.css) and [croppie.js](https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie/blob/master/croppie.js) files, but to no avail. However, I strongly suspect the problem lies in the js file. It might have something to do with the the css *transform-origin* property or the functions for obtaining the image dimensions returning different values on modals. Does anyone have an idea on what the cause of this issue might be?

Answer (score 1):

Got this problem on latest Chrome when used croppie inside of modal
Helped me to change style in bootstrap modal .modal-dialog class
image

[Style that you need to update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64s9M.png)

Setting transform to unset instead of using translate function.

Hope it helps you too

Comment: Thanks! This worked. It seems Croppie is unable to identify "transform" operations on some devices while placing the image in the modal. 

For Croppie to work as intended on every device/browser, you need to avoid applying any sort of transform to the modal, whether for positioning or animation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the extra padding applied to the outer modal div by bootstrap when triggering the modal('show') was what caused the problem, for me at least. Once I removed the extra padding the problem was fixed. Seems like this padding somehow messed with the point calculation when cropping or moving the viewport. I'm still using an older bootstrap version though, so I'm not sure if that would be a fix for the newer ones.

I had this problem on Chrome only probably caused by their last update, since everything was working fine for some time now. On Mozilla there were no issues to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Which div will that be here?
Image B: [codepen](https://codepen.io/amatek/pen/GREvEbG).

Comment: The one with the modal class was in my case. There's no extra margins or paddings in your case in that particular div, however. There might be some kind of spacing coming from elsewhere in your case, if that's indeed the problem. Needs more investigation for sure.